# on_member_update avatar

Tags: python, discord, disnake

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.avatar != after.avatar:
        channel = bot.get_channel(939485737739513886)  
        await channel.send(f"{after.avatar_url}")
```

Бот не выводит новые изображения. Помогите в чем дело?
Все интенты и события включены

Answer (score 0):

У объекта `after` типа [**`discord.Member`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) нет свойства `avatar_url`, к которому вы пытаетесь обратиться.

Но есть свойство `avatar`, как вы уже могли заметить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перейдем в документации к [описанию свойства `avatar`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.User.avatar) и увидим, что свойство имеет тип [**`Asset`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Asset):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У которого, в свою очередь, есть свойство `url`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше логично, что получить ссылку на аватар можно следующим образом:

```py
after.avatar.url
```

---

*Пользуйтесь документацией и будет меньше вопросов :)*

Можете ознакомиться с [**руководством.**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/using_docs.md#%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-discord-py)

Comment: Все равно не работает)

Comment: Я если что, на disnake пишу)

Comment: Проверьте, чтобы были выданы намерения (и добавьте это в текст вопроса, чтобы можно было убедиться, что все выдано правильно). Если все ок, то проверьте, выполняется ли у вас условие `if before.avatar != after.avatar` и вообще, вызывается ли обработчик события `on_member_update`

Comment: ```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.avatar != after.avatar:
        channel = bot.get_channel(939485737739513886)  
        await channel.send(f"{after.avatar.url}")
```

в итоге такой код